# show loading text on pjax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loading, show-hide

i have a script that uses pjax for loading pages. i want to show a loading "loading..." text while request is making, and show until the page fully loads. when ajax makes a call...

```
        pjax.connect({
        'container': 'pageContent',
        'beforeSend': function(){console.log("before send");},
        'complete': function(){console.log("done!");}
    });
```

in the firebug console it sends this messages. so i am thinking maybe, with the beforesend and complete function it is doable. i have poor knowledge on javascript, so maybe some one of you could show me how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct - you can use the 'beforeSend' to show the 'Loading...' message, and the 'complete' event to remove it:

```
  pjax.connect({
    'container': 'pageContent',
    'beforeSend': function(){ $('#LoadingMSG').show(); },
    'complete': function(){ $('#LoadingMSG').hide();}
  });
```

This assumes you have an element with ID set to LoadingMSG:

```
<div id='LoadingMSG'>Loading...</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: dude thnx. i updated the code wth yours and add hide options at start so that it wont show on start only show when pjax calls. :)

       `<script type='text/javascript'>
      $(document).ready(function()
       {
        $('#loading')
            .hide()
   });
  //PJAX links!
       pjax.connect({
       'container': 'pageContent',
       'beforeSend': function(){ $('#loading').show(); },
       'complete': function(){ $('#loading').hide();}
         });
  //pjax.connect('pageContent', 'pjaxer');
  //pjax.connect('pageContent');
  //pjax.connect();
  
         </script>`

Answer (score 0):

```
   <div id='main'>
     <div class='loader' style='display:none'><img src='spin.gif'></div>
     <div class='tabs'>
       <a href='/explore'>Explore</a>
       <a href='/help'>Help</a>
     </div>
   </div>


   $('a').pjax('#main').live('click', function(){
     $(this).showLoader()
   })
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).pjax(...).live is not a function